# Relative URI not working in BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a method for loading an image for later use via binding.

When I set it up as follows it works:

```
public static ImageSource LoadImage()
{
    return new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("C:/User/Name/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Project/bin/debug/subfolder/sprite.png", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

However, when I swap to simply using:

```
public static ImageSource LoadImage()
{
    return new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("/subfolder/sprite.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The XAML doesn't show an image. I looked at `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and it returns `"C:/User/Name/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Project/bin/debug/"`

I've googled around for a solution but can't seem to see anything.

Comment: Are you sure the image is there? Is the path correct (have you tried `./sub/sprite` or `sub/sprite`)? Have you tried to put the sprite into the project, and made sure you set it to "Always Copy" or "Copy when newer"?

Comment: Yes, I'm confident it's there because it works when I use the absolute path, just not when trying the relative one. I've also tried the leading period, and removing the leading slash, no luck.

Comment: I can't seem to get relative `Uri` objects to work in general. It only works when I use an absolute path.

Comment: Workaround:  `return new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"/subfolder/sprite.png")));`

Answer (score 1):

You should load the image from an assembly resource file.

Make sure that the image file is located in a Visual Studio project folder named `subfolder` and set its Build Action to `Resource`. Then load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static ImageSource LoadImage()
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/subfolder/sprite.png"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must leave the leading `/` from the relative URI, which makes the path rooted and thus ignores the complete directory structure of any base URI:

```
var baseUri = new Uri("C:/User/Name/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Project/bin/debug/");
var relative1 = new Uri("/subfolder/sprite.png", UriKind.Relative);
var relative2 = new Uri("subfolder/sprite.png", UriKind.Relative);

// file:///C:/subfolder/sprite.png
Console.WriteLine(new Uri(baseUri, relative1));

// file:///C:/User/Name/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Project/bin/debug/subfolder/sprite.png
Console.WriteLine(new Uri(baseUri, relative2));
```

[Live example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4YywKs)

---

**Update:**

As for the `BitmapImage` itself: As usual, the official WPF help really has some room for improvement.

- It's not mentioned at [`BaseUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.baseuri) that its default value is actually `pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/WindowName.xaml` rather than the current working directory.
- And though there are some examples at [`UriSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource) (mixing whether the path is rooted or not) they forgot to mention that this works only if the sources are embedded resources. They really could have placed a link to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

If you don't want to pack the images as resources, then you have two options:

#### Solution 1: use the StreamSource property instead

Of course, the documentation of [`StreamSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource) property is also very scarce, it only mentions that you should set `CacheOption` to `OnLoad` to close the stream right after loading the image. But simply setting the `StreamSource` will not work so the complete solution:

```cs
public static ImageSource LoadImage(string relativePath)
{
    var bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.BeginInit();
    bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bmp.StreamSource = File.OpenRead(relativePath);
    bmp.EndInit();

    return bmp;
}
```

#### Solution 2: set BaseUri

If you don't mind overwriting that default `pack://...` value in `BaseUri` the correct solution is as follows:

```cs
// as described above relativePath should not be rooted so use
// just "subfolder/sprite.png" without the leading /
public static ImageSource LoadImage(string relativePath)
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(relativePath, UriKind.Relative))
    {
        BaseUri = new Uri(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    };
}
```

Comment: Why the `baseUri` address must be passed, why it is not relative to `CurrentDirectory`?

Comment: I used a specific `baseUri` only for demonstration purpose (which was actually the `CurrentDirectory` of the OP), to make it clear how a rooted path overrides the directory info when combined with anything. Most APIs combine relative paths with the `CurrentDirectory` anyway. So the actual answer to the original question is the first sentence, and the code is just for demonstration/explanation.

Comment: see the comment of the OP, `return new BitmapImage(new Uri("subfolder/sprite.png", UriKind.Relative));` this not work, you can test yourself.

Comment: Sometimes it is very useful to use relative path in production. Let's focus on the question: Is it possible to pass a relative address to BitmapImage? The answer so far is no. you can test with this: https://github.com/dovid-lt/relativePathUriWithBitmap

Comment: @dovid: You were right, mea culpa. Turns out that when used in a WPF window the default value of `BaseUri` is a `pack://...`, URI that refers the assembly and the container window name. It worked for me in a console app because `BaseUri` is `null` if there isn't any context. I updated the answer. Please let me know if it answers your question now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to be in your output folder. Add your image to your project, in Build Action select "Content", and "Copy Always" in your Copy to output directory option.

You will get your image in the output and you will be able to load it using your Relative URI command.

Answer (score 0):

Although I saw your comment, I can tell you for sure, you need to remove the leading slash.

There is no problem with this syntax:

```cs
return new BitmapImage(new Uri("subfolder/sprite.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

I wouldn't trust completely `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, because I don't know how BitmapImage is handling relative uri.

You can try running the executable manually, making sure "subfolder" is in the same folder.

Another option, of course, is to get the full path instead:

```cs
var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath("subfolder/sprite.png");
return new BitmapImage(new Uri(fullPath, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Answer (score 0):

See an example with different path definitions:

```cs
    public class ImageUriViewModel
    {
        public Uri AbsoluteUri { get; }
        public Uri RelativeUri { get; }
        public Uri AbsoluteFromRelativeUri { get; }
        public Uri AssemblyRelativeUri { get; }
        public ImageSource AbsoluteImage { get; }
        public ImageSource RelativeImage { get; }
        public ImageSource AbsoluteFromRelativeImage { get; }
        public ImageSource AssemblyRelativeImage { get; }

        public ImageUriViewModel()
        {
            // Full path on my computer.
            string AbsolutePath = "C:/Users/EldHa/Мои проекты/CyberForurm/CyberForurmWpf/Febr20y/bin/Debug/Images/sprite.png";

            // Relative path on my computer.
            // Note: there is no leading slash!
            // The leading slash is interpreted as the path from the Root folder on the current drive.
            string RelativePath = "Images/sprite.png";


            AbsoluteUri = new Uri(AbsolutePath, UriKind.Absolute);
            RelativeUri = new Uri(RelativePath, UriKind.Relative);
            AbsoluteFromRelativeUri = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(RelativePath));
            AssemblyRelativeUri = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), RelativePath)));

            AbsoluteImage = GetImage(AbsoluteUri);
            RelativeImage = GetImage(RelativeUri);
            AbsoluteFromRelativeImage = GetImage(AbsoluteFromRelativeUri);
            AssemblyRelativeImage = GetImage(AssemblyRelativeUri);
        }

        private static ImageSource GetImage(Uri uri)
        {
            try
            {
                return new BitmapImage(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return NotFile;
            }
        }

        private static readonly ImageSource NotFile;

        private static readonly double pixelsPerDip = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(new UIElement()).PixelsPerDip;

        static ImageUriViewModel()
        {
            FormattedText text = new FormattedText("Not\r\nFile",
                                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                    new Typeface("Tahoma"),
                                    12,
                                    Brushes.Black,
                                    pixelsPerDip);
            Geometry textGeometry = text.BuildGeometry(new Point());

            GeometryDrawing drawing = new GeometryDrawing(null, new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), textGeometry);
            NotFile = new DrawingImage(drawing);
            NotFile.Freeze();
        }
    }
```

```xml
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ImageUriViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid Background="AliceBlue" Columns="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AbsoluteUri}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding AbsoluteImage}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeUri}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding RelativeImage}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AbsoluteFromRelativeUri}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding AbsoluteFromRelativeImage}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AssemblyRelativeUri}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding AssemblyRelativeImage}" />
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

1. In XAML Designer Studio:

- AbsoluteUri and RelativeUri work correctly;
- AbsoluteFromRelativeUri the value is relative to the folder Windows/System32;
- AssemblyRelativeUri the value is relative to the folder with cash Studio.

2. When launched for execution from the folder with the exe file (including run in the Studio) - everything works correctly.
3. When launched for execution from another folder (for example, a shortcut on the Desktop):

- AbsoluteUri, RelativeUri and AssemblyRelativeUri work correctly;
- AbsoluteFromRelativeUri defines the path relative to the current folder.

Answer (score -2):

It will not include your image in final build if you're not using it anywhere in your project and it marked as a 'Resource'. Click on your image and in 'Build action' field select 'Content' instead.