# C# WPF Image Control is not changing when it bound to view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to change an Image control when I press the hotkey, so I wrote a xaml and a view model below:

```xml
<Page
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EZ2ArchiveClient.View"
      xmlns:EZ2ArchiveClient="clr-namespace:EZ2ArchiveClient" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:EZ2ArchiveClient.ViewModel" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewmodel:MainViewModel}" x:Class="EZ2ArchiveClient.View.MainPage"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="600"
      Title="MainPage"
      Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <DockPanel>
        <Image x:Name="CapturedImage" Source="{Binding CapturedImage}" Stretch="Fill" />
    </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

```cs
internal class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapSource? capturedImage;
    public BitmapSource? CapturedImage  
    {
        get
        {
            return capturedImage;
        }
        set
        {
            capturedImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CapturedImage");
        }
    }

    public void HandleCapturedImage()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Handled");
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("captured.png", UriKind.Relative);
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        capturedImage = bitmapImage;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Although not in the source above, I have confirmed that if I press Alt+F12 (a custom hotkey), the image is saved in the program folder under the name `captured.png`. If hotkey input is detected, the hotkey-detecting function calls `HandleCapturedImage` as soon as captured.png is saved. But Image control doesn't show me anything. No errors were found even when debugging. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In HandleCapturedImage(), you set the field, not the property, thus skipping the OnPropertyChanged call.

Comment: `capturedImage = bitmapImage;` should be `CapturedImage = bitmapImage;`  (the property instead of the field... that's why i use `_capturedImage` for fields.

Comment: I just changed ```capturedImage``` to ```CapturedImage```, but the Image control is still not changing.

Comment: Does it work with an absolute path instead of the relative path? If yes, the answers here might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839487/relative-uri-not-working-in-bitmapimage

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11880946/1136211